# CRM 2011 using Func<> in CreateQuery adds all entities to attached entities in xrmServiceContext

Tags: lambda, entity, dynamics-crm-2011, func

When I'm passing a

```
Func<EntityType,bool> sourceFunc = a => a.Name == "name";
```

to:

```
var crmEntities = m_xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<EntityType>().Where(sourceFunc);
```

and then call

```
int i = crmEntities.ToList().Count;
```

it puts all the entities of EntityType in xrmServiceContext attached entities which is 488 entities!

But if instead of Func<> I use the original lambda expression, like so:

```
var crmEntities = m_xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<EntityType>().Where(a => a.Name = "name");
```

and then call

```
int i = crmEntities.ToList().Count;
```

it will return only 1 entity in the attached entities.

I want to use the Func<> but I dont think that I want to have all those entities in the attached entities in xrm service context. Any idea why it puts them all there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intresting..The solution was to pass

```
Expression<Func<EntityType,bool>>
```

Instead of

```
Func<EntityType,bool>
```

And it returned only 1 entity to attached entities :)